# How to reduce my minSdkVersion on my module?

Tags: android, module, build.gradle, versioning, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I developed a networking module for my company. The initial defaultConfigs we set defined minSdk as 29 and it was with these settings that version 1.0.0 of this module was published. Now the need arose to reduce this value to 26 or even less, if possible. I already changed the minSdkVersion to 26 in the module and published a new version, but I always get the same error:

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 26 cannot be smaller than version 29 declared in library [nearsea-technologies:android.network:1.0.1] (...)/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c729ae7e60a0cde9500d48b107ed3b46/transformed/android.network-1.0.1/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 26
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 26,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 29,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="nst.android.network" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

This is the defaultConfig of my module and my current project is the same.

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 33

        (...)
    }
```

How can I resolve this? What do I need to do? What am I missing?

If you need more code, I can make it available.

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifext.xml for your module just add line:

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="nst.android.network" />
```